# How to use ListAnimate to show a series of ListPlots?

Tags: plotting, animation

It's possible that this may be tagged as a duplicate question, but I have been searching this site and the rest of the internet for at least 2 hours looking for an answer to no avail.

I have a series of lists of 200 lines of x and y values (let's call them DataList1, DataList2, etc.) For example:

```
DataList1=[{150, 15745.7}, {152, 15571.2}, {154, 15401.}, {156, 15253.2}]
```

I used ListPlot on each individual list of x and y values which gives me a very nice graph (Graph1, Graph2, etc.) For example:

```
Graph1 = ListPlot[DataList1, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}]
```

After creating each graph (and assigning a variable name to each graph) I would now like to use list animate to show one graph, then the next one, and so on. However, if I use the code:

```
ListAnimate[Graph1, Graph2, Graph3]
```

it does not create the animation box, it only shows a list of each plot as a thumbnail.

There are a total of 19 Graphs / Lists that are to be included in the series.

What am I doing wrong?????

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: How about `ListAnimate@List[Graph1,Graph2, ...]`?

Comment: It's a good idea to look at the documentation first, before googling.  The syntax shown there is `ListAnimate[{expr1, expr2, ...}]` and not `ListAnimate[expr1, expr2, ...]`.  Those brackets are very very important.  Pay attention to them.  For example, your question above contains `DataList1=[{150, 15745.7}, ...`, which is not valid syntax and won't evaluate in Mathematica, all because of wrong use of brackets.

Comment: It was indeed the missing brackets around my expressions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not give the data, I generate it:

```
lst = Table[Table[{x, x^a}, {x, 0, 10, 1}], {a, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
```

Now, this is the list of plots:

```
table = ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {0, 10},PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}] & /@ lst;
```

You can evaluate it and have a look at the results. This makes the animation:

```
ListAnimate[table]
```

Try it. The result looks as follows:

[image]

I attract your attention to the requirement that the argument of the `ListAnimate` must be itself a `List`, as it is in my example and in the comment of Myridium.

On the other hand, if you give only a sequence of plots as the arguments of the `ListAnimate`(like this):

```
ListAnimate[table[[1]], table[[2]], table[[3]], table[[4]]]
```

Mma returns this

[image]

which is what you, probably, observed. The advise is, therefore to enter curly braces:

```
ListAnimate[{Graph1, Graph2, Graph3}]
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you!! That gives me a good template for the future!