# Creating a list of ListPolarPlot snapshots to animate

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, animation

I'm trying to create a list of "snapshots" of the function ListPolarPlot to create a exportable gif or animation. My attempt is somewhat taken from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126296/how-to-use-listanimate-to-show-a-series-of-listplots). The idea is to create this list of "snapshots" and then use the function ListAnimation to create the movie.

[image]

However, it gives the below error. My goal is to create a exportable gif or animation of this plot

[image]

The inputs theta and polarray are lists of angular and radial coordinates in polar coords, respectfully. They represent a numerical approximation of time-dependent planetary motion.

All suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Where are `θ` and `polarray`?

Comment: They're the inputs for making the plot. They're just simple lists of doubles.

EDIT: I suspect my issue is almost certainly that I poorly understand how to implement pure functions using #, &, @ etc.

Comment: try replacing `& /@ {theta, polarray}` with  `& @@@ {theta, polarray}`

Comment: It `θ` and `polararray` are lists, you could replace `{#1, #2}` with `{#[[1]], #[[2]]}`, and `{θ, polararray}` with `Transpose[{θ, polararray}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the OP was unable/unwilling to produce the `θ` and `polarray` lists, I'm making my own:

```
orbit[θ_] = With[{a = QuantityMagnitude[PlanetData["Earth", "SemimajorAxis"]],
                  b = QuantityMagnitude[PlanetData["Earth", "SemiminorAxis"]]}, 
                 b^2/(a + Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[θ])]

θList = N[Range[0, π/2, π/32]];
rList = orbit[θList];
```

From there:

```
data = Transpose[{θList, rList}];
frames = Table[ListPolarPlot[Take[data, k], Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
                             PlotMarkers -> Style["×", Large], 
                             PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2]],
               {k, Length[data]}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: some cartoon]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!